# jquery datatable.min.js sorting issue?

Tags: jquery, datatable

In my project, i am using the jquery pagination of jquery.dataTables.min.js.  In that when i use ascending or descending in query, it will not displayed properly.  The problem is
result can be shown in form of :

```
Sl. No.
1
10
11
12
13
|
|
|
19
2
3
4
5
```

like this,  But i need the result

```
Sl. No.
1
2
3
4
5
|
|
9
10
11
12
13
```

This is because of jquery only.  I want to know how can i clear this?  But in someplace it is displayed properly and in someplace is not displayed properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this one, in first column i used the checkbox for some purpose.  So it will the take the order by their own.  So i put the serial no is first and checkbox is send and solve this problem.

Thank for all guys those who answer.

Answer (score 2):

In the [Datatables documentation](http://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html) it says that the plugin will recognize numeric columns automatically and sort them correctly. Maybe one of your rows contains something that is not an number, and that makes the plugin sort the column alphabetically?

Click "Show details" under sType on this page for an example how to set the sort type manually: http://www.datatables.net/usage/columns